# Is there a way to use PHP from two different html files?

Tags: php

I am trying to make a user-pass system with PHP alone, using arrays instead of using sql (I don't know if this is the right approach). I am defining variables from 2 different html files like this:

```
$user = $_POST['user']; // From signup.html
$pass = $_POST['pass']; // From signup.html  
$email = $_POST['email']; // From signup.html    
$user2 = $_POST['userlog']; // From login.html
$pass2 = $_POST['passlog']; // From login.html
...
```

The code with using these variables (the dot-dot-dot) doesn't do anything and it's like I haven't even declared them in the first place. I have looked at include and require before but I don't know how to use them so I think that might be what I have to do somehow.

Comment: I don't understand, how are you using arrays instead of MySQL? They have nothing to do with each other. One is a medium for storage, one is used for transferring information using a single variable.

Comment: Sounds like you need to use session variables. Ordinary variables don't persist after a script ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is vague, so I will try to give you a general hint to get started. You will need to work from there to whatever you actually want to achieve:

You certainly can refer to a single php script from various other files, also from html files, since php can be embedded in html. All you have to do is include that script in your html files:

```
<html>
<head>
  ...
</head>
<body>
  ...

  <?php include path/to/script.php" ?>

  <h1>Some title</h1>

  <?php if ($user = "alf") then { ?>
    <h2>Hello Alf!</h2>
  <?php } else { ?>
    <h2>Sorry, I do not know you...</h2>
  <?php } ?>

  ...
</body>
</html>
```

This however is not exactly a typical way to implement an application logic.

Instead what is typically done is:

1. don't use html files, but only php scripts. Those can contain or output html markup, no problem there, but coding is easier that way round.
2. don't try to reinvent the wheel, there are many many ready-to-use solutions for user management. Don't make every mistake again others already made.
3. use a database, if you do not want to use mysql then maybe sqlite3 is an alternative, it is easier to setup and sometimes enough, though it certainly is much much slower than a mysql server.

Comment: Everybody has to start somewhere, making a user system is a good start.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to specify that I'm a beginner at PHP and I don't exactly understand how everything works so this was helpful.

Comment: @FieryDolphin376 I recommend you start working through two or three tutorials. That allows to learn a bit about best practices and how to setup things.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your form redirect to a PHP file you can use this:

```
$user = ((isset($_POST['user']))? $_POST['user'] : ((isset($_POST['user2']))? $_POST['user2']) : ''));
$pass = ((isset($_POST['pass']))? $_POST['pass'] : ((isset($_POST['passlog']))? $_POST['passlog'] : ''));
$email = ((isset($_POST['email']))? $_POST['email'] : '');
```

It uses `isset()`, more information about that here:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php